# Docker entrypoint.sh for self-updating programs

Tags: java, shell, docker, signals, docker-entrypoint

I want to run a (java) application in a docker container. This application has an *update* functionality. This is run automatically on startup and can be triggered manually from the (web) GUI. The update downloads the new files, then runs the new executable (with new PID) and exits itself.

Usually, I use the `exec java -jar MyProgram.jar "$@"` in `entrypoint.sh`. This will stop the container when an update occurs (because PID=1 exits).

Just using the line without `exec` does not correctly forward `SIGTERM`/`SIGKILL` for `docker stop`. While forwarding these signals is possible as explaned [here in `program.sh`](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.r5371l1zb), I don't know how to track PIDs when an update occurred and a new process is spawned.

***Update:** Since I am not the developer of the application, I am looking for a solution without modifying the applications.*

***Update 2:** I found out that the application creates a `MyProgram.pid` file which I can read to kill it with the help of a `trap` as explained in `program.sh` linked above.*

Answer (score 0):

Typically we bake jars into an image. If we update the jars in a container at runtime, when we stop the container we lose those changes. Normal upgrade practice is to update your app spec with the new jars and rebuild it into an image using a pipeline of some sort, then replace your containers with the new ones.

Comment: Thanks! Although your approach is recommended when you develop an application yourself, I neither have access to the source code nor the build process.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't going to change the 'physics' of docker. You literally cannot do what you're suggesting because when the container stops, the changes are lost whether you have the source or not. You have to find another way to do the updates. This isn't a recommendation, it's a hard requirement of using docker.

Comment: First, when a container stops (without being removed), all files remain in the writable layer and are not lost. Second, I want to avoid stopping the container but keep the updated process running.

Comment: Well, yes, but nobody relies on that. What's the point in having the container? You're using a container as an old-fashioned server. You're gaining nothing from containerisation, except for the drawbacks of added complexity and an increased attack surface. Why would you do that? It makes no sense. Just run the container, do the upgrade, copy out the new files and build a new image using them just as you have with your current container (I assume, given that you say that you don't have the source, that you've t least built the container yourself, otherwise this makes even less sense).

Comment: I use the container as a lightweight virtual machine. This way, I protect the host from the application. Also I can use a separate container for every application so that they don't interfere.

Comment: But you're introducing significant complexity and an extra attack vector by doing that. It's really not a very good idea and it's not what the technology was intended for (and therefore isn't well supported). You run into all sorts of problems (like this one) that nobody can help you fix. You're better off running lightweight vms if that's what you really need -- at least that's a well understood technology and usecase. What you have is the worst of all worlds. You should rethink this, but good luck with it.